how to use multithreads of "SCIP" in "PYOMO"?
I set solver.options['parallel/maxnthreads'] = 16, but found the solution time did't decrease.
I installed it directly through conda install with a version of 9.1.0, and I wonder if I need to compile it myself, like https://scipopt.org/doc/html/CONCSCIP.php.

Based on what mentioned on the SCIP host:

The parameters parallel/maxnthreads and parallel/minnthreads can be
used to configure the number of threads that sould be used for
solving. SCIP will try to use the configured maximum number of
threads. If the problem that is currently read is too large SCIP will
automatically use fewer threads, but never go below the configured
minimum number of threads.

You will need to define something like this:
  m.Options = {"limits/time": 10, "parallel/maxnthreads": 16}
  SolverFactory('scip').solve(m, tee= True, options = m.Options, load_solutions=True).write()

and the result shows:
reading user parameter file <scip.set>
===========================

limits/time = 10
parallel/maxnthreads = 16


Thank you for your answer! But this doesn't seem any different than setting solver.options directly, at least on the output of the log. In addition, I would like to add that I am currently solving global NLP problems, and I wonder if this will have any impact.

@ZhiyuZhang, in regards to impact, I suggest taking a look at this SO question, and both its answers.
